# How to replace a word in a line that has a character using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file, its content is something like this

```
#Time value
2.5e-5 1.3
5e-5 2.7
7.5e-5 1.1
0.0001 5.9
0.000125 5.8
0.00015 3
......
```

How can I replace the line that is with letter `e` in it (the scientific notation), so that the final file would be

```
#Time value
0.000025 1.3
0.00005 2.7
0.000075 1.1
0.0001 5.9
0.000125 5.8
0.00015 3
......
```

Is shell script able to do this?

```
for (any word that is using scientific notation)
{
    replace this word with decimal notation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1~/e/{printf "%f %s\n", $1,$2}$1~!/e/{print}' file
0.000025 1.3
0.000050 2.7
0.000075 1.1
0.0001 5.9
0.000125 5.8
0.00015 3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're familiar with the [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function in C, there's a similar built-in shell command:

```
$ printf '%f' 2.5e-5
0.000025
$ printf '%f' 5e-5
0.000050
```

To use this in a script, you could do something like:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line = \#* ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    else
        printf '%f ' $line
        echo
    fi
done < times.txt
```

This goes through some trouble to skip the `#Time value` comment. If you could get rid of that line, then it'd be even simpler:

```
while read a b; do printf '%f %f\n' $a $b; done < times.txt
```

Comment: Okay, but how to find which line and which word containing `e` and do this `printf()`?

Comment: @Daniel you can do that with `awk` easily.